# Bank Details for personal payment method by country in oracle payroll

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle payroll R12. I have a client with 7 different payrolls. Each payroll is for a different country where they have branches. While defining an employee, you can go to the Assignment view and click on Others -> Pay Method to enter bank details for an employee.
My question is, how can we choose only a list of local banks for each different country payroll? So that for a US employee we only select American banks, while for a British employee (attached to a British payroll) we only get to choose British banks

Answer (score 0):

Are all 7 payrolls in a different business group? Are you using Oracle payroll for a few or all of these 7 countries, or only Oracle Hr ?

Anyway, you have to define **organisational** payment methods, within each business group, and there you define the bank segments, which have a value set you can restrict to the payroll the employee belongs to.